# (Luke 8:42-47 / Mark 5:25-35) Is Jesus Christ's Surprise Proof of Distinct Characteristic of the 3 persons in the Triune God/Trinity?

Tags: matthew, luke, trinity, attributes-of-god

Is Jesus Christ's Surprise Proof of Distinct Characteristic of the 3 persons in the Triune God/Trinity?

> Luke 8:42-47 New American Standard Bible (NASB)
>     42 for he had an
>   [c]only daughter, about twelve years old, and she was dying. But as He
>   went, the crowds were pressing against Him. 43 And a woman who had a
>   hemorrhage for twelve years, and could not be healed by anyone, 44
>   came up behind Him and touched the fringe of His [d]cloak, and
>   immediately her hemorrhage stopped. 45 And Jesus said, “Who is the one
>   who touched Me?” And while they were all denying it, Peter said,
>   “Master, the [e]people are crowding and pressing in on You.” 46 But
>   Jesus said, “Someone did touch Me, for I was aware that power had gone
>   out of Me.” 47 When the woman saw that she had not escaped notice, she
>   came trembling and fell down before Him, and declared in the presence
>   of all the people the reason why she had touched Him, and how she had
>   been immediately healed.
>
> Mark 5:25-35 New American Standard Bible (NASB)
>
> 25 A woman who had had a hemorrhage for twelve years, 26 and had
>   endured much at the hands of many physicians, and had spent all that
>   she had and was not helped at all, but rather had grown worse— 27
>   after hearing about Jesus, she came up in the crowd behind Him and
>   touched His [a]cloak. 28 For she [b]thought, “If I just touch His
>   garments, I will [c]get well.” 29 Immediately the flow of her blood
>   was dried up; and she felt in her body that she was healed of her
>   affliction. 30 Immediately Jesus, perceiving in Himself that the power
>   proceeding from Him had gone forth, turned around in the crowd and
>   said, “Who touched My garments?” 31 And His disciples said to Him,
>   “You see the crowd pressing in on You, and You say, ‘Who touched Me?’”
>   32 And He looked around to see the woman who had done this. 33 But the
>   woman fearing and trembling, aware of what had happened to her, came
>   and fell down before Him and told Him the whole truth.

In my opinion, the fact that Jesus Christ was surprised by the fact that power left him suggests to me that The Holy Spirit within Jesus Christ(but distinct from Jesus Christ Himself) might have been The Power or caused the Power to leave Jesus Christ.

The Power in turn would heal the physically sick lady.

Therefore, it seems like The Holy Spirit within Jesus Christ may have acknowledged and acted in response to said lady's act of faith, but Jesus Christ's surprise suggests that the leaving of said power should be credited to The Holy Spirit as opposed to Jesus Christ himself.

Therefore, Is Jesus Christ's Surprise Proof of Distinct Characteristic of the 3 persons in the Triune God/Trinity?

Comment: This seems to be an exact duplicate of your previous question [Is delayed realization .... etc](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/45624/luke-842-47-mark-525-35-is-delayed-realization-awareness-proof-of-distinct).

Comment: Unless you equate Jesus to His physical form and not to His Spirit inside a physical body, you cannot arrive at this conclusion. Besides He volunteered to give up His glory and was therefore reliant on God the Father and God the Holy Spirit whilst in a carnal biological machine we call a body. A body being limited by design would cause such a reaction, especially since He voluntarily suppressed His divine attributes such as omniscience. Had He not He would not have been surprised

Comment: It may be (I emphasise _may be_) the case that The Son is unaware of the _focus_ of His Power being used by the Person of the Holy Spirit, whilst He is aware of the _fact_ of His Power being used. That may well be but without considerable research, not just involving this, single, tex; but involving a wide range of texts, I think we cannot - we just cannot - be dogmatic about it, enough to say it is 'proof'. I appreciate the _motive_ of the question but I cannot support the _prosecution_ of it, I am afraid. Not personally.

Answer (score 3):

We know that the Son is not aware of the timing of the end of time. It is not revealed to him, for he says so himself, Matthew 24:36 and Mark 13:32.

The Person of the Father is aware of something but the Son is not.

Whether, or not, the Spirit (who searcheth the deep things of God, 1 Corinthians 2:10) knows from the Father but does not reveal to the Son ; or does not himself know : well, we know not.

But what we do know is that one Person of the Deity may know something and another not so.

So, here, it *may* be the case (I repeat may be) that the Son is not aware of the *focus* of the power within him being used by the Holy Spirit but he is aware of the *fact* of the power being used.

But this place, alone, without further support and without a wider scope, I feel is insufficient for us to be dogmatic.

It gives us a little insight into the Deity and into the Person of Deity.

The two texts together are certainly thought-provoking but I would refrain from saying they, without considerable researched support, are 'proof' of any kind.

Answer (score 3):

Full disclosure - I hold Trinitarian beliefs.

The argument presented in this question for the third person of the Godhead, the Holy Spirit" is very dangerous because it equates the Holy Spirit with the power of Jesus or God.

This is precisely the argument used by "Binitarians"* who say that the Holy Spirit is merely the power of God at work in the world and people, but that during Jesus' incarnation He used only the power of God; hence the references in the question of being surprised by exiting power.

Therefore, the real issue here is: What was the source of power that healed the bleeding woman?  Was it (a) from God via Jesus, (b) from Jesus Himself, or (c) from the Holy Spirit via Jesus?  The text does not say but says that power "went out".  Therefore, I will not presume to supply what the scriptures do not.

*** Appendix BINITARIANISM**

Binitarianism is one of various forms of Arianism that denies the personhood of the Holy Spirit.  In Binitarianism there are two co-equal, co-eternal beings that comprise the Godhead and that the Holy Spirit is the just the outworking of God's power in the world and in people.

Comment: Your caution agreed with. (+1).